# Better way to assign a value with nullable field in dart

Tags: dart, dart-null-safety

Is there a better way to do this?

```
Assignment(
 dueAt: json['due_at'] == null ? 
               null : 
               DateTime.parse(json['due_at']).toLocal()
)
```

The attribute "dueAt" in **Assignment** class can be null and i need to parse the string of json['due_at'] to a DateTime, but json['due_at'] can be null too.

Is not really a problem right now but seems noisy and repetitive.

Comment: There's currently no language construct make that simpler (see https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/360).  In the meantime, you could write a helper function so that you don't need to evaluate `json['due_at']` multiple times.

Comment: Thanks @jamesdlin, I think that's the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First and foremost, it looks like you're writing JSON serialization code by hand. Your life will be much easier and less bug-prone if you let a library do this instead. `json_serializable` is very simple and powerful and 100% worth looking into.

However, this pattern is still common outside of json code.

You could also consider writing an extension method for `Object?` that behaves like the Kotlin standard library's `let` function (https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/let.html)
You can then use Dart's `?.` syntax to handle the rest of the logic:

```dart
// extension on T rather than Object? to maintain type information
extension Example<T> on T {
  R let<R>(R Function(T) function) => function(this);
}
```

This just applies a given function to `this`, which isn't incredibly useful on it's own, but allows the use of `?.`:

```dart
final DateTime? dueAt = json['due_at']?.let(DateTime.parse);
```

If `json['due_at']` evaluates to `null`, the `?.` operator short-circuits, and `dueAt` is set to `null`. Otherwise, it evaluates to `DateTime.parse(json['due_at'])`.

Or, you could just use `package:kt_dart` which ports much of the Kotlin standard library to Dart

Comment: Thanks for you response. Actually the json is from a http response, but your approach looks good.

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case you may want to use `tryParse` instead of `parse`. If `dueAt` is of type `DateTime?` you can simply call:

```
Assignment( dueAt: DateTime.tryParse(json['due_at'])?.toLocal() );
```

Be aware though that `tryParse` will return null for *any* invalid date string (be it null or an improperly formatted string). This may or may not be desired behavior depending on your intended use.

Comment: Good one. I think i will use this for Datetimes, but for a "global" use case i will write a helper function as @jamesdlin pointed out. Thanks for your response.